# Blazor WASM (hosted) redirected on manually entered URL

Tags: c#, http, blazor, webassembly

I've a Blazor WASM (hosted) Application. Everything is working fine. Except for the Situation if I manually enter a URL to a page.

For ex. I've a page "RsetPw2.razor".
The code is as follows:

```
@page "/Auth/respw2"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
@layout AccountLayout
@inject IAuthService AuthService
@inject ISnackbar Snackbar
@inject NavigationManager navMgr


@if (usTok == null || usEm == null)
{
    <MudContainer>
        <MudCard style="margin-top:60px; width:80%;" Elevation="5" Class="pa-auto ml-auto mr-auto">
            <MudCardHeader>
                <MudText Typo="Typo.h5">Reset your Password (step two)</MudText>
            </MudCardHeader>
            <MudCardContent>
                <MudAlert Severity="Severity.Error" Variant="Variant.Filled">This page can not be called without a valid token and a valid user email address!</MudAlert>
            </MudCardContent>
            <MudCardActions>
                <MudButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" Disabled="true" Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" Class="ml-auto">Register</MudButton>
            </MudCardActions>
        </MudCard>
    </MudContainer>
}
else
{
    <EditForm Model="@user" OnValidSubmit="@HandleReset">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <MudCard style="margin-top:60px; width:80%;" Elevation="5" Class="pa-auto ml-auto mr-auto">
            <MudCardHeader>
                <MudText Typo="Typo.h5">Reset your Password</MudText>
            </MudCardHeader>
            <MudCardContent>
                <MudTextField Label="Email address" Disabled="true" HelperText="Max. 8 characters" @bind-Value="@usEm" For="@(() => user.UserEmail)" />
                <MudTextField Label="Reset token" Disabled="true" Class="mt-3" HelperText="the token you'vet got by mail'" @bind-Value="@usTok" For="@(() => user.ResetToken)" />
                <MudTextField Label="New Password" HelperText="Choose a strong password" Class="mt-3" @bind-Value="@user.NewPassword" For="@(() => user.NewPassword)" InputType="InputType.Password" />
                <MudTextField Label="repeat new Password" HelperText="Repeat the password" Class="mt-3" @bind-Value="@user.ConfirmPassword" For="@(() => user.ConfirmPassword)" InputType="InputType.Password" />
            </MudCardContent>
            <MudCardActions>
                <MudButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" Class="ml-auto">Reset Password</MudButton>
            </MudCardActions>
        </MudCard>

    </EditForm>

}

@code {
private UserPwResetModel user = new UserPwResetModel();
private StringValues tok = String.Empty;
private StringValues em = String.Empty;
private string usTok { get; set; } = String.Empty;
private string usEm { get; set; } = String.Empty;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    var uri = navMgr.ToAbsoluteUri(navMgr.Uri);
    if (QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query).TryGetValue("token", out tok))
    {
        usTok = Convert.ToString(tok);
    }
    if (QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query).TryGetValue("um", out em))
    {
        usEm = Convert.ToString(em);
    }
}

private async Task HandleReset()
{
    user.ResetToken = usTok;
    user.UserEmail = usEm;
    var res = await AuthService.ResetPassword(user);
    if (!res.Success)
    {
        snackMessage(res.Message, Severity.Error, Defaults.Classes.Position.BottomRight);
    }
    else
    {
        snackMessage(res.Message, Severity.Success, Defaults.Classes.Position.BottomRight);
        var Count = 3;
        var tmr = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(_ =>
        {
            if (Count > 0)
            {
                Count--;                    
            }
            if(Count == 0)
            {
                Snackbar.Clear();
                navMgr.NavigateTo("/Auth/login");
            }
        }), null, 1000, 1000);
    }
}

// show a snackbar message
private void snackMessage(string message, MudBlazor.Severity type, string position)
{
    Snackbar.Clear();
    Snackbar.Configuration.PositionClass = position;
    Snackbar.Add(message, type);
}
```

}

When I now enter the URL `https://localhost:7076/Auth/respw2`, I'm being automatically redirected to `https://localhost:7076`.

If I navigate to the URL within the Application using `NavigationManager.NavigateTo`, the page works without any hassle.

I have really no idea, where and why the redirect occurs.

I hope someone has an idea...

PS: I forgot to mention: I've tested that with a blank Blazor WASM(hosted) Application. And there I can manually enter a URL to an existing page. So it must be a problem with my application :-(

Comment: if i use NavigationManager.Navigate("/Auth/respw2") it goes to https://localhost:7076/Auth/respw2

When i am at https://localhost:7076/Index and paste the url https://localhost:7076/Auth/respw into the the browsers url field, the browser says loading and then redirects to https://localhost:7076/Index

Comment: sorry, the forgotten 2 was only a type here :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, after a long time of testing. I found no reason for this this problem!

I've solved it by doing the following:

1. create an ne empty Blazor WASM (asp.net core hosted) project
2. delete all components, services and controllers
3. copy the pages, components, services and controller from the non working project and paste them into the new blank project.

The routing works by manually entering a url. Very strange...